# My smooth scrolling js doesn't trigger the animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am not getting this, the page just jumps to the id and not with an animation.
Also the alert "click" is not showing?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   alert('start');
    $('ul#menu-sde-menu li a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
        alert("click");
        var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));

        if (target.length) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }

    });
});
```

and a simple menu

```
<ul id="menu-sde-menu"><li><a href="http://localhost/testdomain/sde/#link1">link 1</a></li><li><a href="http://localhost/testdomain/sde/#link2">link 2</a></li></ul>
```

I tried to use 
https://www.abeautifulsite.net/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use absolute paths `http://localhost/testdomain/sde/#link2`

simply:

```
href="#link2"
```

(if you're planning to stay on the same page anyways, logically.)

You're using `a[href^="#"]` - which means get elements having `href` attribute which **starts with** `^=` an `#`, and `http://` is clearly not one.

Comment: ah i see thanks. i am using wordpress and indeed i have the absolute path and not just the anchor